# Fit grouped curves by label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

While making a nomogram of Remotion related to Depth and Time of sedimentation, I need to fit curves (as paraboles) to remotion labels if they are lower than its upper ten (7 ceils to 10, and 18 to 20). This is very close to what I need.

```
data.frame(
    depth=rep(seq(0.5, 3.5, 0.5), each=8),
    time=rep(seq(0, 280, 40), times=7),
    ss = c(
        820,369,238,164,107,66,41,33,
        820,224,369,279,213,164,115,90,
        820,631,476,361,287,230,180,148,
        820,672,558,426,353,287,238,187,
        820,713,590,492,402,344,262,230,
        820,722,615,533,460,394,320,262,
        820,738,656,574,492,418,360,303)
) %>% 
transmute(
  depth = depth,
  time = time, 
  R = 100*(1- ss/820)
) %>%
  mutate(G=factor(round(R, digits=-1))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=depth, colour=time))+
  geom_label(aes(label=round(R)))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")+
  geom_path(aes(group=G))
```

[image]

But it is not getting parabolical curves. How can I smooth them under the tens condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for. I separated the data and the plot and applied `stat_smooth` for each group. Unfortunately, the smoothed lines do not follow the color scheme. You will also see several warnings do to the method in which this creates the splines.

```
plt <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=time, y=depth, colour = time)) +
    geom_label(aes(label=round(R))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
    geom_path(aes(group=G), size = .6, alpha = .5)

lapply(1:length(unique(df1$G)),
       function(i){
         df2 <- df1 %>% filter(G == unique(G)[i])
         plt <<- plt + 
           stat_smooth(data = df2, size = .5,
                       aes(x = time, y = depth), 
                       se = F,  method = lm, color = "darkred",
                       formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, knots = nrow(df2)))
       })
```

[image]

You can extend this further with additional parameters. I'm just not sure exactly what you're expecting.

```
plt <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=time, y=depth, colour = time)) +
    geom_label(aes(label=round(R))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse") +
    geom_path(aes(group=G), size = .6, alpha = .5)

lapply(1:length(unique(df1$G)),
       function(i){
         df2 <- df1 %>% filter(G == unique(G)[i])
         # u <- df1 %>% {nrow(unique(.[,c(1:2)]))}
         plt <<- plt + 
           stat_smooth(
             data = df2, size = .5,
             aes(x = time, y = depth), 
             se = F,  method = lm, color = "darkred",
             formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, knots = nrow(df2),
                                       degree = ifelse(nrow(df2) <= 4,
                                                       3, nrow(df2) - 2)))
       })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something more like ![this nomogram plot about floculant sedimentation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marco-Carbone-2/publication/235222656/figure/fig2/AS:669088560971776@1536534552064/Example-of-iso-removal-curves-from-settling-analysis.ppm). I thought those isoremoval curves where  fitted by a cuadratical polynom. Not pretty sure but this approach works. Thanks!